# Return dynamic object property with type info

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following problem:

The `getValue()` function works perfectly fine and gets the desired value. However the type information is lost during this process and the type becomes any.

I know how to solve this with a type cast however it would be nice if this cast can be done in the class itself, if needed via a hack. Is this possible?

```
class hi {
    five = 5;
    foo = '3';

    getValue(val: string) {
        // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'hi'.
        // No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'hi'
        return this[val]  // this will always return any because TS can infer the type
    }
}

const hey = new hi();

// I would like this type to be number by adding additional logic in the class
const numberFive = hey.getValue('five'); // type any

// I would like this type conversion to be handled in the class if this is possible
const numberFive2 = hey.getValue('five') as number; // type number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Foo {
  five = 5;
  foo = '3';

  getValue<T extends keyof this>(val: T): this[T] {
    return this[val];
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();

const stringFoo = foo.getValue('foo');   // string
const numberFive = foo.getValue('five'); // number
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, really helpful